# pg_rewind complains about wal_log_hints parameter, when I want to fix timeline differences

Tags: postgresql

I have patroni/postgresql cluster. when I rebooted leader node in patroni cluster, It has timeline differences after boot

pg_rewind command needs wal_log_hints parameter and so I have configured wal_log_hints=on parameter on cluster-wide. Then tested again with reboot

But pg_rewind command still complains about wal_log_hints

```
$pg_rewind --target-pgdata=/var/lib/postgresql/14/main --source-server="host=10.0.20.241 port=5433 user=postgres"
pg_rewind: fatal: target server needs to use either data checksums or "wal_log_hints = on"
```

So when I check this paramter on leader node I mean 10.0.20.241, it is already configured as on
postgres@pat02:~

```
$ psql -p 5433 -U postgres -h localhost -c "select name, setting, applied, error from pg_file_settings where name like 'wal_log%';"
     name      | setting | applied | error 
---------------+---------+---------+-------
 wal_log_hints | on      | t       | 
(1 row)
```

So how can I use pg_rewind ? To recover timeline issue with patroni reinit command is painfull

Thanks

Comment: `wal_log_hints` should have been enabled in the past. At least before the last checkpoint before the point of divergence.

Comment: @Melkij I configured wal_log_hints in the past. So I restarted all 3 nodes to apply wal_log_hints configuration and then tested 

Before the test there is no timeline issue, after test (rebooted leader node) timeline issue occured again

Comment: If `pg_rewind` complains, you did not have `wal_log_hints` enabled from the time where the instances diverged.

Comment: Hello @LaurenzAlbe I did not understand you clearly.

My process was like below

I configured wal_log_hints to on
I restarted all the patroni nodes
I checked wal_log_hints parameter in nodes that is ok
Then tested problem with rebooting the leader node

Comment: That is hard to believe.